# Summing 2D NumPy array by multiple labels

Tags: python, array, mathematics, numpy

> 1. Each element of the array is a coordinate `(x, y)`.
> 2. Each coordinate has two labels.
>
> Goal:
>       sum the elements that have the same two labels.

How can this be made faster?

```
import numpy
from scipy import ndimage

label1 = numpy.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2])
kinds_of_label1 = 3

label2 = numpy.array([0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1])
kinds_of_label2 = 2

data = numpy.array([[1, 2], [3, 8], [4, 5], [2, 9], [1, 3], [7, 2]])
data_T = data.view().T

### processing ####
label1_and_2 = label1 * kinds_of_label2 + label2

result = numpy.empty((kinds_of_label1 * kinds_of_label2, 2))
result_T = result.view().T

result_T[0] = ndimage.measurements.sum(
    position.T[0], labels=label1_and_2,
    index=range(kinds_of_label1 * kinds_of_label2)
)

result_T[1] = ndimage.measurements.sum(
    position.T[1], labels=label1_and_2,
    index=range(kinds_of_label1 * kinds_of_label2)
)

### output ###
print(result)
# [[  3.   4.]
#  [  1.   2.]
#  [  8.  15.]
#  [  0.   0.]
#  [  0.   0.]
#  [  1.   6.]]
```

Comment: In your example code, where does `position` come from?